# Parsing A Table In Google Sheets, Then Storing All Matching Rows Data In An Array I Can Pull Info From (GAS/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, database, for-loop, parsing, google-apps-script

Sorry if my code is messy, I am new to coding. I have been able to make things work up until now.

I want to parse my database, grab info from all rows with the matching criteria and store that info in an array, with each set of data on a new level of the array. So I can print that information later on a report page.

The issue:

When I debug this code, the "newArray" variable has the correct number "objects", for lack of proper coding language, but the contents of each is "function ()" without any real data in them. So something about how I am pushing and or getting the data inside my for loop isn't working properly and I'm not quite sure why.

```
function kanbanView() {

var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//  var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE");
var activeRange = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveRange();
//  var activeCell = activeSpreadsheet.getActiveCell();
var activeCell = activeSheet.getRange(19, 10);
// ^^ remove later, mock cell for debugger.
var activeCellRow = activeCell.getRow();
var activeCellColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
var lastColumn = 17;
var firstColumn = 1;
var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
var activeCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
var findCriteria = activeCellValue;
var foundCriteria = 0;
var contentRange = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 5000, 17);
var contentRangeValues = contentRange.getValues();
var contentRangeFormats = contentRange.getFontColors();
var sourceColumn = 10;

//-------------------------------------------Parsing--------------------------------------------------

var foundValues = [];
var newArray = [];
var foundRow;

var iName;
var iStatus;
var iRating;
var iAction;
var iPosition;
var iLocation;
var iClient;

for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
if (activeColumnRangeValues[i][0] == findCriteria) {
foundRow = i;

iName = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE").getRange(foundRow, 7).getValue;
iStatus = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE").getRange(foundRow, 5).getValue;
iRating = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE").getRange(foundRow, 4).getValue;
iAction = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE").getRange(foundRow, 6).getValue;
iPosition = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE").getRange(foundRow, 8).getValue;
iLocation = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE").getRange(foundRow, 9).getValue;
iClient = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("ACTIVE").getRange(foundRow, 10).getValue;

newArray.push([iName, iStatus, iRating, iAction, iPosition, iLocation, iClient,
]);
foundValues.push(foundRow + 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
function kanbanView() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("ACTIVE");
  const vA = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),17).getValues();
  const findCriteria = sh.getRange(19, 10).getValue();
  const newArray=[];
  const foundValues=[];
  vA.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r[0]==findCriteria) {
      newArray.push([r[6],r[4],r[3],r[5],r[7],r[8],r[9]]);
      foundValues.push(i+1); 
    }
     
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(foundValues));
}
```

This my data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 | COL17 | COL18 | COL19 | COL20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 29 | 23 | 28 | 9 | 22 | 1 | 23 | 2 | 5 | 20 | 4 | 27 | 7 | 5 | 24 | 22 | 17 | 26 | 4 |
| 2 | 18 | 17 | 18 | 29 | 22 | 25 | 26 | 11 | 10 | 22 | 17 | 14 | 5 | 18 | 28 | 27 | 7 | 13 | 25 |
| 4 | 18 | 0 | 20 | 25 | 25 | 24 | 12 | 23 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 26 | 13 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 4 | 27 | 18 |
| 27 | 23 | 28 | 23 | 9 | 29 | 14 | 25 | 26 | 8 | 9 | 25 | 6 | 12 | 14 | 0 | 29 | 21 | 29 | 2 |
| 21 | 1 | 25 | 13 | 10 | 4 | 3 | 26 | 21 | 10 | 7 | 15 | 5 | 29 | 4 | 26 | 8 | 23 | 13 | 17 |
| 19 | 7 | 22 | 16 | 7 | 27 | 15 | 2 | 27 | 19 | 29 | 12 | 9 | 29 | 11 | 21 | 6 | 0 | 28 | 9 |
| 25 | 12 | 5 | 23 | 7 | 28 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 4 | 26 | 6 | 6 | 12 | 27 | 10 | 21 | 0 | 14 | 27 |
| 17 | 22 | 8 | 28 | 18 | 18 | 7 | 13 | 6 | 18 | 21 | 13 | 27 | 28 | 10 | 29 | 4 | 13 | 10 | 11 |
| 17 | 6 | 8 | 17 | 18 | 2 | 10 | 6 | 3 | 13 | 1 | 13 | 16 | 2 | 7 | 11 | 22 | 11 | 8 | 8 |
| 20 | 27 | 10 | 19 | 5 | 29 | 23 | 12 | 18 | 16 | 1 | 19 | 1 | 5 | 24 | 27 | 18 | 10 | 4 | 1 |
| 28 | 5 | 3 | 17 | 14 | 16 | 10 | 3 | 20 | 28 | 28 | 4 | 8 | 26 | 16 | 22 | 24 | 28 | 12 | 27 |
| 12 | 13 | 17 | 22 | 8 | 12 | 22 | 8 | 21 | 29 | 22 | 18 | 14 | 15 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 14 |
| 15 | 16 | 27 | 29 | 5 | 11 | 10 | 8 | 7 | 10 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 8 | 22 | 19 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| 27 | 28 | 23 | 12 | 3 | 23 | 21 | 26 | 16 | 28 | 17 | 5 | 19 | 13 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 28 | 0 | 12 |
| 21 | 12 | 18 | 29 | 15 | 1 | 24 | 9 | 1 | 14 | 18 | 27 | 29 | 20 | 8 | 4 | 22 | 10 | 19 | 0 |
| 21 | 0 | 4 | 23 | 23 | 3 | 27 | 21 | 4 | 24 | 21 | 20 | 18 | 28 | 20 | 13 | 9 | 2 | 4 | 22 |
| 15 | 13 | 19 | 14 | 16 | 28 | 2 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 25 | 10 | 1 | 10 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 10 | 17 |
| 10 | 1 | 3 | 17 | 8 | 1 | 7 | 16 | 0 | 21 | 29 | 22 | 25 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 0 | 18 | 15 | 12 |
| 11 | 11 | 21 | 5 | 9 | 13 | 13 | 3 | 12 | 6 | 15 | 9 | 4 | 12 | 19 | 28 | 1 | 1 | 25 | 18 |
| 19 | 15 | 24 | 15 | 15 | 3 | 27 | 13 | 27 | 29 | 28 | 29 | 28 | 23 | 26 | 13 | 4 | 26 | 20 | 25 |
| 11 | 18 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 17 | 4 | 15 | 15 | 10 | 15 | 6 | 5 | 21 | 6 | 19 | 26 | 18 | 11 | 16 |
| 6 | 10 | 3 | 21 | 1 | 5 | 9 | 4 | 20 | 25 | 1 | 0 | 27 | 11 | 7 | 23 | 2 | 11 | 17 | 21 |
| 21 | 0 | 10 | 19 | 18 | 4 | 17 | 13 | 2 | 27 | 5 | 10 | 16 | 25 | 6 | 24 | 26 | 12 | 15 | 6 |
| 2 | 26 | 8 | 11 | 14 | 18 | 25 | 14 | 0 | 24 | 29 | 6 | 10 | 22 | 17 | 1 | 16 | 23 | 4 | 3 |
| 17 | 2 | 19 | 17 | 21 | 29 | 25 | 14 | 7 | 6 | 10 | 14 | 24 | 1 | 11 | 2 | 25 | 22 | 21 | 26 |
| 13 | 27 | 25 | 16 | 10 | 14 | 1 | 6 | 12 | 27 | 18 | 26 | 25 | 0 | 16 | 16 | 1 | 4 | 9 | 23 |
| 29 | 16 | 1 | 22 | 26 | 28 | 4 | 16 | 28 | 15 | 29 | 12 | 13 | 18 | 26 | 21 | 3 | 25 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 21 | 26 | 27 | 5 | 26 | 17 | 22 | 0 | 21 | 4 | 0 | 27 | 12 | 25 | 5 | 25 | 7 | 8 | 5 |
| 23 | 24 | 29 | 1 | 2 | 20 | 19 | 5 | 21 | 2 | 13 | 9 | 27 | 24 | 20 | 4 | 4 | 21 | 4 | 4 |
| 29 | 0 | 22 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 18 | 24 | 28 | 0 | 22 | 23 | 8 | 21 | 1 | 5 | 13 | 20 | 11 | 12 |

This is my results:

```
4:21:10 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:21:11 PM  Info    [[3,10,13,4,26,21,10],[24,15,29,1,9,1,14],[27,23,23,3,21,4,24],[17,18,19,4,13,2,27]]
4:21:11 PM  Info    [6,16,17,24]
4:21:11 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```